# Modding Terraria myself?

Tags: mods, terraria

How do I convert all of the image files to .PNG's, and once I do have them in an editable form, how do I get them to be used by the game client? Is there something I will have to download to do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you intend to create a texture pack?

Comment: Just for my own use but basically yes.

Comment: Sorry, @DomenikVanBuskirk.  This is off-topic for Arqade; we're about playing games, not modding them.  Gamedev.SE might work, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use TerrariaTexturePack and a rarfile of converted stock images (all the XNB files pre-converted over to PNG) from [here](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/how-to-install-texture-packs-list.40054/). If for some reason you'd rather, [this tool](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/xnb-exporter-extract-graphics-from-terraria.16058/) can extract the individual PNG files from each XNB. For reference, TerrariaTexturePack is the tool which allows Terraria to use your custom PNGs, and it's impossible to convert back to XNB (a proprietary, game-specific format created by XNA Game Studio).

Comment: I should've figured someone already converted them to PNG for download. Thanks for links also